# What Cocoa class would be appropriate to create a custom modal dialog?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

All I need is a simple text-entry dialog where the user can add a memo and either accept or cancel it.  I would like it to behave as a modal dialog that I can customize.

This would essentially behave as a UIAlertController type 'Alert'; but with a UITextField (or UITextView) for message entry; with two buttons.

**Is there a simple cocoa 'dialog' class that does this?**

The keyword here is 'modal' in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple dialog class in iOS. UIViewController is the class you should use; just present it modally. You can set the modalPresentationStyle of the presented controller to UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen (so the previous controller's view shows underneath), and set its size to something smaller than full screen if you want.